# How to change Canvas.Zindex property through c# code in UWP

Tags: vector, uwp-xaml

i want to change Canvas.Top value by c# on button click for that i use

Canvas.SetZIndex(Button1, 4);
 but it give error .

Comment: Could you provide the error log?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to change Canvas.Top value by c# on button click for that i use

If you want change Canvas.Top value of button where under `Canvas`, you could use [`Canvas.SetTop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.settop) static method.

**Xaml**

```
<Canvas Width="640" Height="480" >
    <Button Name="Btn" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="30" 
     Background="Red" Width="200" Height="200" Click="Button_Click" />
</Canvas>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.SetTop(Btn, 500);
}
```

But this method is a utility method for the property system, and isn't used in most app scenarios. In most cases you set the Canvas.Top XAML attached property in XAML and won't need this method. The better way that you could use `DependencyObject.SetValue`. And it also works.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    Btn.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 100);
}
```